# iText nested table inside a cell

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating a PDF with iText version 2.1.0. I have to create a "detail" cell in a cell of a table. I did this nesting a table inside that cell. The problem with this approach is that the borders of the nested table don't touch the borders of the container cell. What I am looking for is for a table nested inside a cell whose borders don't differenciate from the nested table borders.

I have a test like this one. I do this inside a loop to add tables inside a cell to the outer table:

```
PdfPCell testCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Test"));
//I want this border to touch the containerCell borders.
testCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.BOTTOM);
testTable =  new PdfPTable(2);

testTable.addCell(testCell);
testTable.addCell(testCell);
testTable.addCell(testCell);
testTable.addCell(testCell);

PdfPCell containerCell = new PdfPCell();
containerCell.addElement(testTable);
outerTable.addCell(containerCell);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think I finally found it:

```
testTable = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell c2;
testTable.addCell("aaaa");
testTable.addCell("bbbb");

c2 = new PdfPCell (testTable);//this line made the difference
c2.setPadding(0);
outerTable.addCell(c2);
```

The trick here is using the table in one of the PdfPCell constructor.

Comment: Why is c1 there, but not referred to?  Is that needed?

Comment: I guess is a typo. It should be most probably c2. I will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I found that what was causing my tables to be smaller than the enclosing cell was that I was not adding the following code to the table:

```
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you identified,

```
cell.setPadding(0);
```

is what you needed.

Comment: Yes, but I found that doing this way

c2 = new PdfPCell();
c2.addElement(testTable);
c2.setPadding(0);

doesn't work the same way as 

c2 = new PdfPCell (testTable);
c2.setPadding(0);
outerTable.addCell(c2);

In the first case you can see the nested table borders.

Comment: Yes, when using AddElement the added element's properties are used. When using the constructor the table cell's properties are used instead of whatever are the properties of the added element.